# How to setup TLS for an NS record subdomain

Tags: ssl, dns, subdomain

I have an NS record setup for my.domain.com, which then resolves as `http://my.domain.com >> https://thirdparty.domain.com`

I need to setup a TLS certificate for `my.domain.com` so that it can be reached at `https://my.domain.com >> https://thirdparty.domain.com`

`my.domain.com` is managed in AWS, and as far as I know getting a certificate requires that certificate to live on a server. Whereas, the NS record seems to just point the domain at a server outside of my control. `thirdparty.domain.com` is a third party service.

Am I understanding this correctly? How/where will I need to setup the TLS certificate for `https://my.domain.com`

Example:

my.domain.com NS record:
`some.thirdparty.server.`

Results in `302: http://my.domain.com > RES: https://thirdparty.domain.com`

I would like:
`302: **https**://my.domain.com > RES: https://thirdparty.domain.com`

In practice this is the flow:

```
main.domain.com POST >>
302: http://my.domain.com >>
RES: https://thirdparty.domain.com
```

Comment: I think your example removed critical information to answer the question. Can you improve it more like https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve ?

Comment: does that help?

Comment: What service/server is answering with a HTTP 302 redirect on `http://my.domain.com` ?

Comment: @JanZerebecki I believe it is the server listed in the NS record `some.thirdparty.server.` Which I don't have access too, I'm beginning to think it may not be possible without access to that server?

Comment: That might theoretically be the same server, but unlikely. The NS record only points to names of the DNS server answering DNS queries, not what those servers answer nor what servers those answers point to via `A` and `AAAA` records. As far as I understood you, you want to change the response from `my.domain.com`, is that correct? What does `my.domain.com` resolve to via which DNS records? Do you have access to `my.domain.com`? Do you use AWS Route53 (you linked to docs of it below)?

Comment: Yes, it is route 53. my.domain.com appears do be doing almost nothing but passing on the DNS someplace else. Imagine the only way to do this is setup a server to receive secure connections, before passing it on to the third party service. Unless anyone has another idea?

Comment: Yes, as far as I understand your question. See my edited answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The system that terminates (where decryption occurs) the TLS connection will need the certificate. The system that responds to a TCP connection on port 443 on the IP address which the domain that you type in your browser ultimately resolves to needs to have the TLS certificate.

> my.domain.com NS record: some.thirdparty.server.

That means the third party controls which servers respond.

> I would like: `302: **https**://my.domain.com > RES: https://thirdparty.domain.com`

As far as I read this, this is about a HTTP redirect from the first to the second. What you would like requires to receive HTTPS connections on `my.domain.com`, to do that the servers that currently receives HTTP there need to also do so for HTTPS.

If you do not control these server and they currently do not answer to HTTPS, then the only way is to handle DNS yourself (i.e. remove the NS record) and point to servers that only do this redirect. (As you are currently using AWS: That is something their services S3 and CloudFront can achieve together.)

Comment: I dont quite understand your answer in the context of my question. I have control over an NS record setup for sub.domain.com (my.domain.com in your example). thirdparty.domain.com is aready accepting connections at 443, sub.domain.com is not> My question i suppose more clearly is: how can i get my.domain.com to accept a 443 connection?

Comment: I dont clearly understand the difference between CNAME vs NS

Comment: DNS has record types like `A` (points to an IP), `CNAME` (points to a different name, like an alias), `NS`. I assume you meant DNS when you said NS, not the record type.

Comment: For `sub.domain.com` you either use a `CNAME` to point at the name of the third party, but then they need to have a certificate for `sub.domain.com`. Or use a reverse proxy on your own server with your certificate to unwrap SSL and rewrap and forward it for the third party.

Comment: No I meant [Name Server (NS) Resource Record Set](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/SOA-NSrecords.html#NSrecords)